How to convert dwg file into shapefile using ezdxf, geopandas and shapely with no missing data
I am new to CAD and GIS and developing a functionality to convert dwg into shapefile using python libraries- ezdxf, geopandas and shapely. I am encountering issues during conversion, the code is utilizing ezdxf addon odafc(Needs ODA File Converter installed and at path) to read dwg file which temporarily converts dwg into dxf and then I am iterating entities in dxf modelspace and fetching points, lines, polygons, annotations and text. Then converting all into their respective geodataframes. After this I plot geodataframes to check if their are any broken lines and incomplete polygons in geodataframe, if they exist, I need to fix them and then save the resulting geodataframe into a shapefile. The issues I am encountering are-

Not able to fetch all points, lines and polygons
Not able to get all the text and text which I get is distorted and not correctly displayed on geodataframe
The function fix_lines sometimes draw additional lines which are not required, thus ruining shapefile
fix_polygons function does nothing, don't know if polygons fetched are correct or not

Any help will be appreciated, if there is some other library which can get job done, please let me know but it should work without needing any other third party software.
Here the python code for same-
import geopandas as gpd
import re, copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ezdxf.addons import odafc
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString, Point, MultiLineString

def sanitize_text(text):
    """Sanitize text by removing invalid Unicode characters."""
    return re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', text)

def convert_dwg_to_shp(dwg):
    try:
        polygons = []
        lines = []
        points = []
        annotations = []

        dxf = odafc.readfile(dwg)
        msp = dxf.modelspace()

        for entity in msp:
            try:
                if entity.dxftype() == 'LINE':
                    points_list = [entity.dxf.start, entity.dxf.end]
                    lines.append(LineString(points_list))
                elif entity.dxftype() == 'LWPOLYLINE':
                    points_list = entity.get_points('xy')
                    if points_list[0] == points_list[-1]:
                        polygons.append(Polygon(points_list))
                    else:
                        lines.append(LineString(points_list))
                elif entity.dxftype() == 'POLYLINE':
                    points_list = [point[:2] for point in entity.points()]
                    if points_list[0] == points_list[-1]:
                        polygons.append(Polygon(points_list))
                    else:
                        lines.append(LineString(points_list))
                elif entity.dxftype() == 'POINT':
                    points.append(Point(entity.dxf.location))
                elif entity.dxftype() == 'CIRCLE':
                    center = entity.dxf.center
                    radius = entity.dxf.radius
                    circle = Point(center).buffer(radius)
                    polygons.append(circle)
                elif entity.dxftype() == 'TEXT':
                    text_content = sanitize_text(entity.dxf.text)
                    position = entity.dxf.insert
                    annotations.append({'text': text_content, 'geometry': Point(position[0], position[1])})
                elif entity.dxftype() == 'MTEXT':
                    text_content = sanitize_text(entity.get_text())
                    position = entity.dxf.insert
                    annotations.append({'text': text_content, 'geometry': Point(position[0], position[1])})

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing entity {entity.dxftype()}: {e}")


        geo_dataframe_lines = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': lines})
        geo_dataframe_lines = geo_dataframe_lines.set_geometry('geometry')
        geo_dataframe_lines.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)

        geo_dataframe_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': points})
        geo_dataframe_points = geo_dataframe_points.set_geometry('geometry')
        geo_dataframe_points.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)

        geo_dataframe_polygons = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polygons})
        geo_dataframe_polygons = geo_dataframe_polygons.set_geometry('geometry')
        geo_dataframe_polygons.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)

        if annotations:
            annotations_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(annotations)
            annotations_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(annotations_df, geometry='geometry')
            annotations_gdf = annotations_gdf.set_geometry('geometry')
            annotations_gdf.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)
        else:
            annotations_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['text', 'geometry'])

        geo_dataframe_lines.plot(aspect=1)
        geo_dataframe_points.plot(aspect=1)
        geo_dataframe_polygons.plot(aspect=1, facecolor='none', edgecolor="green")
        annotations_gdf.plot(aspect=1)
        plt.show()

        return geo_dataframe_lines, geo_dataframe_points, geo_dataframe_polygons, annotations_gdf

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return f"An error occurred: {e}"
    
def fix_lines(geodataframe_lines, geodataframe_points, geodataframe_polygons, annotation_gdf):
    closed_geometries = []

    for index, row in geodataframe_lines.iterrows():
        geom = row['geometry']
        geom_type = geom.type

        if geom_type == 'LineString':
            if not geom.is_closed:
                coords = list(geom.coords)
                if len(coords) > 1:  # Ensure line has at least two points
                    coords.append(coords[0])
                    geom = LineString(coords)
        elif geom_type == 'MultiLineString':
            fixed_lines = []
            for line in geom:
                if not line.is_closed:
                    coords = list(line.coords)
                    if len(coords) > 1:  # Ensure line has at least two points
                        coords.append(coords[0])
                    fixed_lines.append(LineString(coords))
                else:
                    fixed_lines.append(line)
            geom = MultiLineString(fixed_lines)

        closed_geometries.append(copy.deepcopy(geom))

    geodataframe_lines['geometry'] = closed_geometries

    geodataframe_lines.plot(aspect=1)
    geodataframe_points.plot(aspect=1)
    geodataframe_polygons.plot(aspect=1, facecolor='none', edgecolor="green")
    annotation_gdf.plot(aspect=1)
    plt.show()

    return geodataframe_lines, geodataframe_points, geodataframe_polygons, annotation_gdf

def fix_polygons(geodataframe_lines, geodataframe_points, geodataframe_polygons, annotation_gdf):
    closed_geometries = []
    for index, row in geodataframe_polygons.iterrows():
        geom = row['geometry']
        geom_type = geom.type
        if geom_type == 'Polygon':
            exterior = geom.exterior
            if not exterior.is_closed:
                coords = list(exterior.coords)
                if coords[0] != coords[-1]:
                    coords.append(coords[0])
                exterior = LineString(coords)
                geom = Polygon(exterior, geom.interiors)
        closed_geometries.append(copy.deepcopy(geom))

    geodataframe_polygons['geometry'] = closed_geometries

    geodataframe_lines.plot(aspect=1)
    geodataframe_points.plot(aspect=1)
    geodataframe_polygons.plot(aspect=1, facecolor='none', edgecolor="green")
    annotation_gdf.plot(aspect=1)
    plt.show()

    return geodataframe_lines, geodataframe_points, geodataframe_polygons, annotation_gdf


#Call the functions[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/JVnGyC2C.png)

GDAL, the library powering geopandas.read_file, supports reading .dxf files: DXF driver. So if you can convert the .dwg to .dxf, you could try geopandas.read_file("file.dxf")

Thanks for the suggestion, I integrated GDAL, and the shapefiles are better than before, I am able to get more content out of dwg files. But text and annotations are still not showing, is there something which can be used to show text as well?

I've never used it myself, so I'm afraid I cannot help you further...
